# Extract Linear Data to one row from Multi-line - awk

Tags: bash, awk

Similar to [Add Column to text file using Heading value ( mutliple Heading in the file )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767232/add-column-to-text-file-using-heading-value-mutliple-heading-in-the-file) , I would like to extract data where there is a server mentioned , moving to one line.

Example Data

```
server1.domain.com
INFO XYUS
  OTHER INFO XYZ
     IP 1.2.3.4 ( name1.domain.com ) 
     IP 5.4.3.1 ( name1a.domain.com )
server2.domainlong.com
INFO 21323213
  OTHER INFO XYZ
     IP 4.2.3.4 ( nameS.domain.com )
```

I need :

```
server1.domain.com,1.2.3.4,name1.domain.com
server1.domain.com,5.4.3.1,name1a.domain.com
server2.domainlong.com,4.2.3.4,nameS.domain.com
```

So basically in English.

- I need to parse a text file
- Start Collecting when i hit a line ending in domain.com or
  domainlong.com
- Collect only from the line Starting with "IP"
- Generate a row per "IP" line ( can be more than 1 )
- Move onto next set when it ends a new line ending in domain.com or
  domainlong.com

Again , this may be simple **awk** but Im not an expert....

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the term `INFO` just an example or is it really used?

Comment: Hi ! All the data is dummy data. I dont need the line with INFO on it and its too random to use as marker. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `awk` command will do the trick:

```
awk '/domain.*\.com$/{d=$0}/IP/{printf "%s,%s,%s\n",d,$2,$4}' file
```

Explanation:

- If a line ends with `domain.*\.com` we store it into the variable `d`
- If a line contains the term `IP` we print the ip and host name along with `d`

Comment: Hi ! This looks like it will nearly do the trick :) However I have domain.com on the header line and later in the child lines.. So a blind awk may not work?

Comment: It matches `domain.*.com$`. That means it needs to be at the end of the line. In the lines containing `IP`, the hostname is followed by `)`

Comment: Actually it was my bad , I was using "IP" which is Dummy , i cleaned up a little more and its perfect , thank you as always.